# Unable to execute LINQ Where clause with generic lambda expression

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, where-clause

I am trying to develop a generic function that applies a Where clause but the "inputQuery.Where(condition)" statement does not compile. I get "Argument 2: cannot convert from 'System.Linq.Expressions.LambdaExpression' to 'System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<object,bool>>'.

```
   public IQueryable<Object> ExecuteWhereClause(IQueryable<Object> inputQuery, Object typedValue, Type viewType, String paramName, Type paramType)
    {           
        ParameterExpression parameter = Expression.Parameter(viewType);
        Type[] typeArgs = { viewType, typeof(bool) };
        var condition =
             Expression.Lambda(
                 typeof(Func<,>).MakeGenericType(typeArgs),
                 Expression.Equal(
                     Expression.Property(parameter, paramName),
                     Expression.Constant(typedValue, paramType)
                 ),
                 parameter
             );

        return inputQuery.Where(condition);
    }
```

Comment: why you extend `IQueryable<Object>` instead `IQueryable<T>`? in your case you can `Expression.Lambda<Func<object,bool>( Expression.Equal(
                     Expression.Property(parameter, paramName),
                     Expression.Constant(typedValue, paramType)
                 ),
                 parameter)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you a bit confused how expression work with `Where`.

*predicate* parameter in [Where](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb535040(v=vs.110).aspx) function have concrete type

```
Expression<Func<TSource, bool>> predicate
```

where `TSource` - type of element in coolection, in your case you have collection `IQueryable<Object> inputQuery` so `TSource` always is `Object`

and static type for return value - `bool`.

So, even if you somehow convert generic `LambdaExpression` to `Expression<Func<Object, bool>>` you get error, because `viewType` can be not `Object`.

This problem you can solve just create typed `LambdaExpression`

```
var condition =
    Expression.Lambda<Func<object,bool>>(
        Expression.Equal(
            Expression.Property(parameter, paramName),
            Expression.Constant(typedValue, paramType)
        ),
        parameter
    );
```

but now you get another error if `viewType` not an `Object`

> ParameterExpression of type '' cannot be used for delegate parameter of type 'System.Object'

So you have a few way:
first: not avail `viewType` and always use `object` instead, and in this case you get another error when try get property, because you can get only those property that have `object` class.

second: a bit change your function to use generic parameters

`IQueryable<Object>` -> `IQueryable<T>`

create parameter with this `T`

```
ParameterExpression parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T));
```

because you can pass only parameter with this type to lambda `Expression.Lambda<Func<T,bool>>` that available `Where` function.

Use `Expression.Lambda<Func<T,bool>>` - so this really what need `Where` - function that available object with type of element in source collection.

So at end you can get next function:

```
public static IQueryable<T> ExecuteWhereClause<T>(IQueryable<T> inputQuery, object typedValue, String paramName)
{
    ParameterExpression parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T));
    var condition =
            Expression.Lambda<Func<T,bool>>(
                Expression.Equal(
                    Expression.Property(parameter, paramName),
                    Expression.Constant(typedValue)
                ),
                parameter
            );

    return inputQuery.Where(condition);
}
```

or even

```
public static IQueryable<T> ExecuteWhereClause<T,U>(IQueryable<T> inputQuery, U typedValue, String paramName)
{
    ParameterExpression parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T));
    var condition =
            Expression.Lambda<Func<T,bool>>(
                Expression.Equal(
                    Expression.Property(parameter, paramName),
                    Expression.Constant(typedValue)
                ),
                parameter
            );

    return inputQuery.Where(condition);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are building lambda, that requires viewType, it can not work with Object. If You want to do it this way, You have to cast it

```
public IQueryable<Object> ExecuteWhereClause(IQueryable<Object> inputQuery, Object typedValue, Type viewType, String paramName, Type paramType)
{
    ParameterExpression parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Object));
    var condition =
         Expression.Lambda<Func<Object, bool>>(
             Expression.Equal(
                 Expression.Property(Expression.Convert(parameter, viewType), paramName),
                 Expression.Constant(typedValue, paramType)
             ),
             parameter
         );

    return inputQuery.Where(condition);
}
```